# Alternatives to make for linux/freebsd?

Tags: linux, makefile, freebsd

What are some alternatives to [make](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Make_(software)) for linux/freebsd?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I like [SCons](http://www.scons.org). It is constructed in such a way that every build script (a `SConstruct` file) is also a syntactically valid Python program. So, you can build arbitrary Python logic into your build script if you need to.

It's also much faster than `make` and calculates many kinds of dependencies automatically.

Comment: 'scuse me? Faster than make? What ancient hardware are you running make on? Last time I looked, SCons has serious performance issues. Other than that, I like SCons.

Answer (score 6):

My first question would be, what is the audience.  Is this for building in-house software that only your team will build?  If so, explore some of the options already presented.  If this is something that others will be building, either stick with make, or use a tool that creates makefile and ship those.  We use autoconf and automake for Linux and other unix platforms.  In my opinion, you need a very good reason to do something other than configure; make; make install.  Boost has their own tool (a modified version of Jam), and it annoys me everytime I need to try and get it to compile on an unusual machine.

Answer (score 5):

[cmake](http://www.cmake.org/) and [imake](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Imake) are both build utilities, although Imake is no longer maintained.  Cmake is also cross-platform and can be used on Windows as well.

If you're into java, [ANT](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apache_Ant) is a build tool geared to Java (which doesn't really play nicely with Make).

Troll tech make a tool called [qmake](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Qmake), which they use to build QT.  It works by generating makefiles - Troll needed a tool to support a cross-platform build - so you still need another make utility.

Comment: Trolltech has moved out of qmake and into cmake, so I would go for the later instead of the former. CMake generates makefiles as much as IDE projects for a variety of IDEs.

Comment: @dribeas has it correct, QT and I believe the entire KDE project was moved over to CMake.

Comment: I'm not sure why you mention cmake and imake in the same sentence...

Answer (score 4):

Automake :p which is commonly used in most linux app distributions but it gives a bit more work than a Makefile but better results http://www.gnu.org/software/automake/

http://www.openismus.com/documents/linux/automake/automake.shtml <-- nice explanation on how to use automake and autoconf

Comment: Autotools isn't really an alternative for `make`, because in the end it generate GNUMakefiles. So instead of just arcane makefile syntax, you now also have rather old-fashioned shell-scripts and `m4` macros as icing on the cake! In other words, now you have *three* problems.

Answer (score 4):

If you're looking for something completely different, there's [Ant](http://ant.apache.org/).  I'm not that interested in it myself, but it does offer some portability advantages (no reliance on the unix shell, etc.)

Answer (score 4):

I've heard good things about [Jam](http://freetype.sourceforge.net/jam/index.html).

Comment: The link is to Freetype Jam which came from Perforce Jam.  Also derived from Perforce Jam is Boost Jam which is worth a look.  I've been using Jam for over 10 years; I recommend it too.

Answer (score 3):

[OMake](http://omake.metaprl.org/index.html) is a build tool for C/C++, OCaml, and LaTeX with automatic dependency analysis. It easily can build projects over multiple directories, and it finds changes based on MD5 sum rather than timestamp. It also has a mode where it can be run in the background, building your project whenever a file is modified. Generally, it takes less code to build common kinds of projects (C/C++ or OCaml programs and libraries) than make does. I haven't tried it for bigger projects.

Note that if you want to program in OCaml, this tool is really useful since the OCaml linker requires compiled modules to appear on the command line in dependency order, and figuring out this order every time something changes is non-trivial.

Answer (score 3):

I've used CMake for more of my projects, including porting some autotools based ones and I can say that it does its job very well. It's mostly suitable for C/C++ cross platform projects.

Answer (score 2):

The project I'm working on inherited some code that uses `Cons` instead of `Make` (not to confused with `SCons` in Greg Hewgill's answer).

`Cons` is written in Perl, much like `SCons` is written in Python.  It manages dependencies automatically, and you can use any Perl code inside the build script to handle complex build sequences.

The main disadvantage (and the main reason I'm sorry my project uses it) is that `Cons` doesn't do parallel builds in the style of `make -j`.  If you're compiling a number of files that don't depend on each other `Cons` will compile them one at a time, while `make -j` will compile them in parallel, which is great if you have multiple cores and threads on your machine.

Comment: And unfortunately Cons seems to be a dead project; there is no current development on it last time I looked.

Answer (score 1):

Another make for cross-platform builds is `kmake` (a part of `kbuild`, in its own words: *kBuild is a makefile framework for writing simple makefiles for complex tasks.*). It is an enhanced version of GNU `make`. It is developed by the VirtualBox folks. They use it to build their VirtualBox Product for Windows, Linux, MacOS and Solaris. Pretty portable!

See http://svn.netlabs.org/kbuild for details.

Answer (score 1):

[WAF](https://code.google.com/p/waf/) is an interesting alternative. Written in python it allows you to write your build logic in plain Python. Parallel builds + semi-auto-magic signature-based dependency tracking work reasonably well. It's supposedly cross-platform (i.e. knows how to do builds on Windows), but I haven't tried that.

It's got a fairly steep learning curve, but it also comes with ["The WAF book"](http://docs.waf.googlecode.com/git/book_17/single.html) to aid with the process.

Comment: Some time ago I had to look into `waf` to fix a build problem. After looking through the `wscript` I had to dig into the code of `waf` itself. It looks pretty unpythonic. Just for fun I ran `pep8` on the latest version, and it gave 6000 errors and 25000 warnings. To be fair, in the latest release that I just looked at, the authors have added a lot of documentation.

Comment: Looks like the project on github is deleted. Found this instead: https://waf.io/