# configure file template to generate makefile

Tags: c++, linux, makefile

Almost all the opensource c++ project in Linux has a 'configure' file to generate Makefile before building the source code.

I am writing a project from scratch, is there any template for this 'configure' file?

Comment: You may choose to not have any `configure` script.

Comment: Oh, it gets topical halfway down: http://queue.acm.org/detail.cfm?id=2349257

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Most of the time, the configure files are not created by hand, but generated by tools like [autoconf](http://www.gnu.org/software/autoconf/). There are more modern alternatives however, which are mostly easier to use. Have a look at [cmake](http://www.cmake.org/), [qmake](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmake-manual.html) for Qt, or [scons](http://www.scons.org/).

Also have a look at previous questions, e.g. [C++ build systems](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2847730/c-build-systems).

Comment: I haven't used scons for a while, but I recall it didn't used to produce makefiles. Has that changed?

Comment: No, scons doesn't produce makefiles: http://www.scons.org/wiki/FrequentlyAskedQuestions#Compatibility_with_make

Comment: Autoconf is 'modern' and maintained. And it is *easier to use* if you intend to have a correctly working build system. Other systems are most like 'reinvent build system yourself'.

Comment: I did not mean downplay the role of autoconf. I just found e.g. cmake easier to use, and also see a lot of open source packages move over to cmake instead of using autotools these days.

Answer (score 4):

It's generated by a program called [Autoconf](http://www.gnu.org/software/autoconf/).

Comment: Sometimes, the `configure` script is written manually (e.g. for Ocaml or Perl).

Answer (score 4):

The `configure` file is generated through autoconf from a `configure.ac` file. Here's my minimal template for `configure.ac` with C++:

```
dnl Minimal autoconf version supported. 2.60 is quite a good bias.
AC_PREREQ([2.60])
dnl Set program name and version. It will be used in output,
dnl and then passed to program as #define PACKAGE_NAME and PACKAGE_VERSION.
AC_INIT([program-name], [program-version])
dnl Keep helpers in build-aux/ subdirectory to not leave too much junk.
AC_CONFIG_AUX_DIR([build-aux])
dnl Enable generation of Makefile.in by automake.
dnl Minimal automake version: 1.6 (another good bias IMO).
dnl foreign = disable GNU rules requiring files like NEWS, README etc.
dnl dist-bzip2 = generate .tar.bz2 archives by default (make dist).
dnl subdir-objects = keep .o files in subdirectories with source files.
AM_INIT_AUTOMAKE([1.6 foreign dist-bzip2 subdir-objects])

dnl Enable silent rules if supported (i.e. CC something.o instead of gcc call)
m4_ifdef([AM_SILENT_RULES], [AM_SILENT_RULES])

dnl Find a good C++ compiler.
AC_PROG_CXX

dnl Write #defines to config.h file.
dnl You need to generate config.h.in, for example using autoheader.
AC_CONFIG_HEADERS([config.h])
dnl Generate Makefile from Makefile.in.
AC_CONFIG_FILES([Makefile])
dnl This generates fore-mentioned files.
AC_OUTPUT
```

The `dnl` lines are comments (explanations) for you, you can remove them from your file.

It assumes you are using automake to generate the `Makefile` as well. If you don't want that, you need to prepare a `Makefile.in` by hand (and remove the `AM_INIT_AUTOMAKE` line).

The configuration results will be written to `config.h`. You usually include it like:

```
#ifdef HAVE_CONFIG_H
#    include "config.h"
#endif
```

And my template for `Makefile.am` (which is used by automake):

```
# Programs which will be compiled and installed to /usr/bin (or similar).
bin_PROGRAMS = myprogram

# Source files for program 'myprogram'.
myprogram_SOURCES = src/f1.cxx src/f2.cxx
# Linked libraries for program 'myprogram'.
myprogram_LDADD = -llib1 -llib2
```

After creating those two templates, you usually run `autoreconf -vi` rather than random tools yourself. This is going to guess what you need and run it.

Feel free to let you know if you need something more, I'll be happy to explain.