# Event based shell script

Tags: c++, linux, shell, compilation

I have two files which I have to compile. I want to write something like an event based shell script which compiles first file and then the second file. Is it possible to write event based shell script that does action 2 when action 1 is completed.

Comment: Look into http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2847730/c-build-systems

Answer (score 2):

That thing is called [`make`](http://www.gnu.org/software/make) and it allows you to define targets, dependencies and rules.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, just like this:

```
#!/bin/sh
action1
action2
```

Comment: the next question will be: how to check if command succeeded?

Comment: `action1 && action2` will perform the 2nd only if the 1st succeeds

Comment: @AndyT try set -o errexit and it will stop execution if there is an error.